# Вывод времени в Qt

Tags: qt, время

Мне необходимо выводить в `QLabel` текущее время, причем так, чтобы оно обновлялось каждую секунду.

Мой код почему-то не работает:

```
void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *evt)
{
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    ui->TimeLabel->setText(time.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int timerId = startTimer(1000);
...
void void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *evt)
{
    if (evt->timerId() == timerId)
    {
        QTime currTime = QTime::currentTime();
        ui->TimeLabel->setText(currTime.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    }
}
...
killTimer(timerId);
```

Comment: все равно не получается. может, я не там создаю таймер

Comment: 1. В *.h добавить переменную int timerId;
2. в конструкторе - timerId = startTimer(1000);
3. timerEvent() остается как есть
4. в деструкторе - killTimer(timerId);

"Все-равно не получается" - что значит?

Вариант 2:
1. в конструкторе:

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimerTimeout()));
    timer->start(1000);